# Generate random/unique names for variables

Tags: java

I'm trying to generate an unknown amount of buttons by doing this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < itemsList.size(); i++) {
        final String item = itemsList.get(i);
        TButton button = new TButton("" + item, 8, 415 + (25 * i), 90, 25) {
            public void doAction() {
                System.out.println("Item: " + item);
            }
        };
        this.buttons.add(button);
    }

    for (TButton button : buttons) {
        this.framework.add(button);
    }
```

However the framework doesn't accept multiple buttons with the same name, so I am getting an error.

Can i generate random/unique names for each button?

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: gtge.TestGame$1@32301b86     [UIName=Button, bounds=8,415,90,25] [text=Plante] already reside in another container!!!
at com.golden.gamedev.gui.toolkit.TContainer.add(Unknown Source)
at com.golden.gamedev.gui.toolkit.FrameWork.add(Unknown Source)
at gtge.TestGame.update(TestGame.java:78)
at com.golden.gamedev.Game.startGameLoop(Unknown Source)
at com.golden.gamedev.Game.start(Unknown Source)
at com.golden.gamedev.GameLoader.start(Unknown Source)
at gtge.TestGame.main(TestGame.java:96)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < itemsList.size(); i++) {
        final String item = itemsList.get(i);
        TButton button = new TButton("" + item, 8, 300 + (25 * i), 90, 25) {
            public void doAction() {
                System.out.println("Item: " + item);
                //TestGame.this.test = "" + item;
            }
        };
        this.framework.add(button);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about java but I've done something similar in vb with guid's using `guid.newguid()` to create a new unique value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hashCode()` method.

Comment: Seriously? button.hashCode()?